# add a post / upload media to wordpress site through a C# / vb.net application?

Tags: .net, wordpress, xml-rpc

Anyone know if its possible to add a post and upload images to a wordpress blog (self hosted) via a .net application?

I see i could use XML-RPC.net to talk with the wordpress XML-RPC interface, but i see really few documentation and samples around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [JoeBlogs](http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/) library to access the API. Using that, working with the blog is very simple:

```
var blog = new WordPressWrapper("https://svicktest.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php", "svicktest", "mypassword");

byte[] imageData = …;

var image = blog.NewMediaObject(new MediaObject { bits = imageData, name = "Plane.jpg", type = "image/jpeg"});

blog.NewPost(new Post { title = "Hello!", description = "Hello world! <img src=\"" + image.url + "\" />" }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after searching all over the web I finally got what I wanted. Thanks Once again. :)

Comment: @gumuruh Yeah, looks like the new site is https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs.